# android studio can't move button or text in the layout

Tags: android-studio, drag-and-drop

I saw people could just drag button or text in Android Studio tutorials.
I insert a button on layout, but i can't move it freely(I use RelativeLayout).
so how I can solve problem ? Thank you

Comment: Check [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout), it should solve your problem of making the layout editor more responsive.

Comment: @JonGoodwin you're thinking about the wrong type of drag and drop. AFAIK, OP means in the layout editor - which is a part of the IDE and not something you can write code for without editing the source of AS itself.